# C++ way of C# Action += function?

Tags: c#, c++, c++11, lambda, action

in C# we can say:

```
Action act = ()=> {/*stuff*/}; 
act += ()=> {/*another stuff*/}`
```

and then call `act()`.

I wonder how to do such thing in C++ (now  with lambdas it will be quite usefull and if possible not using Boost/Qt signals)?

Comment: What exactly does `+=` do (for those who don't know C#)?

Comment: @Xeo it adds another handler to a delegate method.

Comment: @Richard: And... what happens when you then invoke the delegate? Does it execute all handlers in order? Does it pass the result of earlier handlers to the next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write something like this rather easily, by filling a `std::vector<std::function<void()>>` with the lambdas and invoke every function object.

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

// warning: very crude and likely with typos / bugs
template<class Sig>
struct Action{
  template<typename Functor>
  void operator+=(Functor&& f)
  { _funcs.emplace_back(std::forward<Functor>(f)); }
  template<class... Args>
  void operator()(Args&&... args) const{
    for(auto& f : _funcs)
      f(args...);
  }
private:
  std::vector<std::function<Sig>> _funcs;
};

// ...
Action<void()> act;
act += []{ /*...*/ };
act += []{ /*...*/ };
act(); // invoke all handlers in order
```

However, from what I know, C# also allows you to *remove* a handler with `-=`, which isn't as easy to accomplish in C++. You'd need to return a token from `+=` which can be passed to `-=` to remove that specific handler.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit reckless to forward something more than once?

Comment: You could use `operator -=` by forcing them to use the same object, which I assume is what C# requires anyway. After all, how is it going to know that some other anonymous lambda expression is equivalent without doing an expensive byte code comparison?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Ooh, I see. Yeah. See the warning above the class. :> Simply *not* forwarding them should "work".

Comment: @pickypg: Lambda objects aswell as `std::function` don't offer comparision operators, since it's practically impossible to define what is "equal". You *might* get around with the object address, but for lambdas, you get a *unique* object and type for every lambda expression.

Comment: @Kerrek: I really don't think there's a "best" choice here, since lvalue passing might be wanted and you might want to have the updates propagate to the other handlers.

Comment: @Xeo: Something like `act(std::string("Hello ") + argv[1]);` would result in disaster, non?

Comment: @Kerrek: Why? Inside `operator()`, it's simply an lvalue ref.

Comment: @Xeo You could accept the reference, which would require them to hang onto it as well should they choose to remember it; some mix of `std::function::target`. The returned token (resulting in a `std::map` internally) would certainly work, but I think it would make a much more awkward interface. This is all me talking out of interest, as I haven't had the chance to use C++11 lambda expressions.

Comment: @pickypg: Well, hanging onto a function object (which may be expensive to copy) or a simple token, I think the token is more preferrable. :)

Comment: @Xeo Granted, this may be about of not using it, but it's my understanding that `std::function::target` maintains the reference for you, enabling comparisons without any extra copies.

Comment: @pickypg: Oh, well, for `.target`, you need to know the target type, which may be a problem for lambdas. ;)

Comment: @Xeo So it was a lack of use. Good to know :)

Comment: @Xeo Considering each listener must implement the same target type, right (may I'm misunderstanding the meaning of target here?), we should know the type and therefore we should be able to check the reference. Right?

Comment: @pickypg: No, since `std::function` is a polymorphic function wrapper, which allows you to pass any kind of callable entity to it. You can pass lambdas, function pointers and other function objects. And as I said, *every* lambda expression has a *unique* type.

Comment: A simple option is to make the index into the vector the token.

Comment: @Luc: Not really, since any removed handler would invalidate all tokens following it. Maybe a linked list would work better if you want to remove and have the other handlers not be impacted by it...

Comment: Swap handler with no-op handler, duh. (Kidding, that only works when returning `void`.)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe with `std::function`s:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> act;

act.emplace_back([] { /* stuff */ });
act.emplace_back([] { /* more stuff */ });
```

To call:

```
for (auto & f : act) { f(); }
```

Comment: If someone rolled their own `Action` class, you could easily implement `operator +=` as Xeo does below (only, using your `std::function<void()>`), and it would match perfectly.

Comment: Why not `push_back`? :) `emplace(_xxx)` is for emplace construction and just signals a different purpose.

Comment: @Xeo: Emplacement is the new universal way to go. Since the emplacing constructor subsumes the copy constructor (but also allows for moving!), there's no need to carry around the old cruft.

Comment: Well, `push_back` has an rvalue overload. :) I think it's just the different purposes the functionalities were originally designed for. Also, I think `emplace` allows for `explicit` construction / conversion, while `push_back` does not.

Comment: @pickypg: You certainly could, and if you find yourself using this pattern *a lot*, then please do. Sometimes I like to keep it simple, though, until there's a pressing need to abstract.

Comment: @Xeo: I continue to not see why I shouldn't be using emplacement everywhere. Especially when it comes to map-type containers it cuts down the amount of code by anything between 80% and 120%...

Comment: @KerrekSB Agreed. I only brought it up as it does seem like a very convenient pattern to provide an abstract implementation for. It certainly enables event driven models much more rapidly.

Comment: True, true for map containers. I may just see a different purpose for copy / move construction and emplace construction (and as someone mentioned in the chat, emplacement doesn't quite seem to work with initializer lists or rather, those don't quite seem to work with perfect forwarding).

Comment: @Xeo: Oh OK, I never realized that `insert` lets you use initializer lists. That is indeed a non-trivial distinction.

Comment: @Kerrek: Same for `push_back` I think.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Okay, late reply time! Yes, since `push_back` is typed on the `value_type` of the container. [Live example.](https://ideone.com/MMkQHi)

Comment: @Xeo: I've come around to your point of view by now: emplacement entails explicit conversions, while insert/pushback does not. That said, to complicate matters further, the insert functions for vector and map are different: The former takes a value type, the latter is a template... (as we discussed a short while ago). Lots of subtle distinctions.